# Node.JS function return versus calling that function

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm starting to learn about function callbacks/modules at node school and I was a bit confused

Here is my code: 
So my question is, should I return function_callback or just call it directly. It seems to give me the same results
eg 
return function_callback(err, finalList)

OR

calling function_callback(err, finalList)

```
//prints files in a directory given some extension name

module.exports = function(dir_name, ext_type, function_callback)
{

    //importing needed modules
    var path = require("path");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var finalList = new Array();

    fs.readdir(dir_name, function(err, list)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            function_callback(err);
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                if (path.extname(list[i]) == ("." + ext_type))
                {
                    finalList.push(list[i]);
                }
            }

            function_callback(null, finalList);
        }
    })


};
```

the above is a single file(which I require in my main file)

```
//main file that imports file_ext_handler

//import modules that we need
var file_ext_handler = require("./file_ext_handler.js");

//declaring vars from process arguments
var dir = process.argv[2];
var ext = process.argv[3]

    //reads the directory with is process.arg[2]
    file_ext_handler(dir, ext, function(err, list)
    {
        if (err) 
        {
            throw err;
        }
        else 
        {
            list.forEach(function (file) 
                {
                    console.log(file);
                }
            )
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly a difference in coding style. Doing the early, explicit return lets you save an indention level:

```
function callFoo(cb) {
  foo(function(err) {
    if (err)
      return cb(err);
    // do something else
  });
}
```

versus:

```
function callFoo(cb) {
  foo(function(err) {
    if (err)
      cb(err);
    else {
      // do something else
    }
  });
}
```

It can also help ensure that you don't accidentally execute some code that comes afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

As @mscdex pointed out, returning a function if your condition is met simply saves some code.

```
if(true) return callback(); // won't go any further if the condition is met

// do something else
```

versus

```
if(true) {
    callback(); 
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

However, returning a function in other situations can have benefits, such as having the outer function return the value that the inner function returned... That sounds confusing, so here is a contrived example:

```
function sayHi() {
    return 'Hi';
}

function foo() {
    sayHi();
}

foo(); // returns undefined

// Now, let's have foo() return sayHi()

function foo() {
    return sayHi(); //
}

foo(); // now returns 'Hi'
```

Comment: thanks. it was confusing me because it was the first time i encountered callbacks